# Modificar el tamaño de una NavigationBar embebida dentro de un UINavigationController

Tags: swift, swift2

Tengo mis vistas(UITableViewController) y desde el storyBoard he embebido estas vistas en un NavigationController. El caso es que estoy queriendo modificar el tamaño del NavigationBar que viene dentro del UINavigationController, especificamente estoy queriendo modificar el alto.

Estoy manejando el siguiente codigo dentro del ViewDidAppear para hacer la modificacion.

```
//TESTING NAVIGATIONBAR CUSTOM
    let bounds = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    //let screenHeight = bounds.height



    let nav = self.navigationController?.navigationBar


    nav?.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black
    nav?.tintColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
    // nav?.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, bounds.size.width, 60)
    nav?.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, bounds.size.width, 80)

    //END NAVIGATIONBAR CUSTOM
```

Y la parte de la modificacion funciona, el problema viene cuando ejecuto la app y me aparece una franja vacia entre el navigationBar y la primera celda del UITableViewController.

[image: Franja blanca]

Como puedo evitar la franja?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esa franja no corresponde al `UINavigationController` sino que probablemente es el alto del `header` del `UITableView`.
Implementa el siguiente método del `UITableViewDelegate` tal que así:

```
// MARK: - UITableViewDelegate
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    return CGFloat.min

}
```

Para que el `header` tenga un `height` mínimo y así hacer que no se vea.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN 1**

Después de cambiar el tamaño del `UINavigationBar` debes reajustar los `insets` del `UITableView` para que se ajusten correctamente. Por ejemplo tal que así:

```
nav?.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, bounds.size.width, 80)
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 44, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 44, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

Con el código que has enviado te queda solucionado.

Comment: He implementado la funcion y la franja sigue apareciendo. SI elimino la linea `nav?.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, bounds.size.width, 80)`  la franja desaparece pero el tamaño del navigationBar queda del tamaño por defecto.

Comment: Perdon, no desaparece por completo, pero la franja tiene el grosor de uno o dos pixeles. se reduce segun el tamaño del navBar.

Comment: ¿Sería posible que subieras el código a Dropbox o similar para echarle un vistazo?

Comment: Por supuesto. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4915071/Myapp.zip espero sea de utilidad

Comment: Mañana miraré de encontrar una solución, pero juega con los valores de `tableView.contentInsets` ya que parece problema del `tableView`

Comment: He añadido nuevo código. Saludos!

Comment: Ha funcionado. Gracias @mhergon

Comment: De nada! Cualquier cosa ya sabes